# how to set writeable highwatermark?

Tags: node.js

I found in `options` to set the highwatermark for [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options):
`fs.createReadStream(path[, options])`

but cannot find `highwatermark options` for [writeable stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

So how to set it when creating a writeable stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though it's not documented on `fs.createWriteStream`, a [`stream.Writable`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options) can take: `highWaterMark` as an option.

```
fs.createWriteStream('out', { highWaterMark: 32000 });

console.log(stream._writableState.highWaterMark); // 32000
```

And to actually test that it is working:

```
const lowHWStream = fs.createWriteStream('low', { highWaterMark: 1 });
const highHWStream = fs.createWriteStream('high', { highWaterMark: 32000 });

console.log(lowHWStream.write('a')); // false
console.log(highHWStream.write('a')); // true
```

> The return value is true if the internal buffer is less than the
>   highWaterMark configured when the stream was created after admitting
>   chunk. If false is returned, further attempts to write data to the
>   stream should stop until the 'drain' event is emitted.

[Checking the source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/streams.js#L231), you can see that the options you pass to `createWriteStream` are passed to  `stream.Writable`

Comment: Thank you. It'w werid the nodejs document doesn't point this.

Comment: Does anyone know if `readable` and `writeable` streams (ie, provider and consumer) need to have equal `highWaterMark` values?

Comment: @user1063287 no, they don't need to be equal.